# PHP Dom merge documents

Tags: php, dom, document

Problem with merge documents with DOM and PHP

I need to include a part of an html file from the server in an existing document in a specific position within the original file, for example using a line number within the original document or below a specific node using DOM, how can I do it?

I tried various ways but I was unable to include the part of the file to be added.

How can I do it?

Comment: If you are talking specifically about `DOMDocument`, there's an [append](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.append.php) method, and the documentation even includes examples for how to use it.